# center webrtc video stream content when displaying tall video on wide screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, webrtc

I am making a webrtc video call between a mobile and laptop, the mobile is in portrait mode, so it sends the stream with the height greater than width,  and the laptop send the stream with the aspect ratio reversed.

I want the video to be displayed full screen for which i have used the following css:

```css
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
object-fit:contain;
object-position:50% 50%;
minHeight:100%;
minWidth:100%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

That makes the video fullscreen but the video displays only the top portion of the stream, the rest is cut off, **Is there a way in js, css to make it so that the video displays the center portion of the stream and cuts out edges,** Like how it occurs in the [Apprtc](https://appr.tc/) reference app.

Thank you.

Comment: How is it cut off? Is there another element on top? It's probably a CSS rule of a different element that is causing trouble. Generally speaking it should work with `object-fit: contain`, [as seen here](http://jsbin.com/kificey/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: The aspect ratio of the screen is 16:9 and the stream aspect ratio is 9:16, basically I'm trying to display a  very tall video on a very wide screen , the video displays only the top portion of the actual stream in fullscreen, object-fit:contain doesn't seem to work,  there is no other element on top

Comment: I updated my example with a vertical video. Even when making the screen very wide it scales the video and centers it, much like `background-size: cover;`. Would you be able to share a little more of your CSS or HTML? A screenshot might help, too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchultz , My css was wrong, i had to use object-fit: cover , and had to increase the size of the parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres no need to do so much to center your video. Just use `object-fit: cover;`, (which most modern browsers support) on the display container and all will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Note that this won't work in any version of IE. Not an issue for WebRTC as they don't even support that. http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: @FabianSchultz comment resolved the issue, which was due to me using incorrect css, since he didn't provide an answer, i'll accept yours.